# Uniqueness of SDE solution: Use of Ito's isometry.

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

While I was reading the proof for uniqueness of the solution of SDE it a doubt came to my mind, namely why are we "allowed" to use Ito isometry (under our assumptions).

The theorem I am referring to could be found in "Introduction to stochastic integration" by Kuo.

> **Assumptions**: $\sigma, f$ are measurable functions on $[a,b]\times
>  \mathbb R$, and satisfy Lipschitz condition.
>
> The starting point $\xi$ is an $\mathcal F_a$ measurable r.v. with
>   $E(\xi^2)<\infty$.

He starts by assuming  that $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are two solutions of an Stochastic Integral Equation. Put $Z_t=X_t-Y_t$.

Then $$Z_t=\int_a^t \big(\sigma(s,X_s)-\sigma(s,Y_s) \big)dB(s)+\int_a^t \big(f(s,X_s)-f(s,Y_s)\big)ds$$

Then he uses Cauchy-Schwarz inequality  ($(a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)$), then takes expectations on both sides.

Taking the first term on the right we have

$$\mathbb E\bigg[\bigg(\int_a^t \big(\sigma(s,X_s)-\sigma(s,Y_s) \big)dB(s)\bigg)^2\bigg]$$

At this point he applies Ito's isometry; my doubt is, why are we allowed to apply it?
In order for $X_t$ to be a solution we need $\sigma(\cdot)$ to be adapted and $\int_a^b \sigma(\cdot)^2 ds<\infty $ almost surely, but this does not assure (at least, I am not able to see it) that the difference $\sigma(s,X_s)-\sigma(s,Y_s)$ is square integrable with respect to $P\otimes \lambda$.

Do you mind explaining me how this works?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

In Karatzas book the author actually defines two stopping times

$$\tau_n^{(X)}:=\inf\{t\geq 0: X_t\geq n\}$$
$$\tau_n^{(Y)}:=\inf\{t\geq 0: X_t\geq n\}$$

Then if we work with the stopping times it's clear that

$$\mathbb E\bigg[\bigg(\int_a^{t\wedge \tau_n^{(Y)}\wedge \tau_n^{(X)}}  \big(\sigma(s,X_s)-\sigma(s,Y_s) \big)dB(s)\bigg)^2\bigg]=\mathbb E\bigg(\int_a^{t\wedge \tau_n^{(Y)}\wedge \tau_n^{(X)}}  \big(\sigma(s,X_s)-\sigma(s,Y_s) \big)^2ds\bigg)$$

because the right hand side is finite.

Comment: Yes, the proper way is to use stopping times.

Comment: There's no problem with $\int_0^T \sigma(s,X_s)^2 ds<\infty$ almost surely: the intergand is bounded. However, to take expectations one indeed has to consider stopping times.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your comments, I've been reading Schilling's Brownian Motion book and he makes no use of stopping times at all. This makes me think that I am misunderstanding something. In particular in theorem (18.9) he uses "the maximal inequality for s .integrals". But he is not assuming (at least not explicitly) that the  the $\sigma$ is a square integrable process with respect to the measure $P\otimes\lambda$